# Difference between update and upgrade in ptf

Tags: tools

What is the difference between update and upgrade when using a module in ptf ([Penetration Testers Framework](https://github.com/trustedsec/ptf)) ?

Comment: I think this is a question for the toolset itself. Surely there is help text?

Comment: As this is not a common tool, you might have to include a few more details so that we know what you are talking about.

Comment: No, there is no help option for the tool. About information, it is a tool used to download known security tools for debian and Ubuntu ; it is very useful for guys like me who hates working with Kali.

Comment: Still need more details. How do you "use" a module in ptf? Are you aware of the normal 'upgrade'/'update' difference in Linux?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the normal update upgrade in Linux distributions, and it doesnt seem that ptf have the same concept. This tool looks like metasploit, it is interactive. When we lunch the tool, we use a module (ex : use modules/exploitation/metasploit), in the module we can choose to install, update, upgrade ...

Comment: I'm still going to ask for *specific details* about how you are prompted for and select an update over an upgrade. When I look at ptf, I can only see that there is *no* dual prompt for `upgrade` and `update`

Comment: When you are in a module, you type `help` it will show you the available commands for that module. Between these commands we find update and upgrade. I tried them both, but can't seem to figure out the difference.

Comment: Ok - you have now actually provided all the details you need to look at the code yourself. The code simply says `if prompt.lower() == "update" or prompt.lower() == "upgrade":` meaning that they are the same.

Comment: For open source tools like this, please, please look at the code to sort out these kinds of details. This is the sort of skill that you will need to develop if you want to learn how to hack systems.